# What topics (software) can I ask questions about

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions in regards to software that's not necessarily main stream. I'm a developer of a ERP/inventory system and my clients wants to know if they can ask questions on stack overflow?

Comment: Are you looking to outsource your support questions to Stack Overflow, instead of hosting them yourself?

Comment: I think as long as they are programming related questions that would be fine. If it's how do I do this and that using GUI I think those would be off topic.

Comment: We have a support website but it came up in a discussion with a client, the client is also very technical and they use stack extensively. They wanted to know if they can ask question in regards to our software on stack. The only people that will be able to answer the questions will be clients and the us the developers of the product. The reason they want it in stack is because sometimes our problems relate to environment (windows IIS ect.) so when they search in stack its a one stop shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking your users to write code for you (for example through a proprietary scripting language), then you could probably make a tag here (reputation notwithstanding) and that would go over well. That's what [after-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/after-effects) is for, after all. You'd want to have a pretty substantial user-base under you, of course, but if it became a respected language in the community, I'd see no problem with that. You'd probably want to start off with your own forums first to build up to a point where a tag here wouldn't just generate unnecessary and unbeneficial noise. But I'll leave that explanation for another question.

However, if you're asking us whether it's acceptable to let your users post their tech support questions on Stack Overflow, that's an overwhelming *no*. Just as we would very quickly close the question "How can I change the margins of my Word document on a single page without affecting the others?" we will close your general, not-programming-related questions.

Seeing your comment now about wanting only clients and developers able to answer questions, that *definitely* won't fly. Not only is the system simply not built for that, but it also goes against the philosophy of the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

See: [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

And: [What can I ask about?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thx the answer is no, " However, if you're asking us whether it's acceptable to let users post their tech support questions on Stack Overflow, that's an overwhelming no "

Comment: @FrancoisTaljaard yep, unfortunately it sounds like you're looking for a self-hosted forum. I'm sure there are other frameworks that are built specifically for things like that which you could look into if need be.